# How to add default values in request body of swagger docs while using compojure-api

Tags: clojure, swagger, swagger-2.0, compojure-api

Suppose you have schema like below

```
(s/defschema House
  {:bedroom s/Int
   :bathroom s/Int 
   :parking s/Int
})
```

The dynamic generation of swagger docs will assign a default value of 0.
How do I assign default value for bedroom, bathroom, and parking for swagger docs ?

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve this using [ring.swagger.json-schema](http://metosin.github.io/ring-swagger/doc/ring.swagger.json-schema.html). We can modify our schema using json-schema

```
(s/defschema House
  {:bedroom (ring.swagger.json-schema/field s/Int {:example 3})
   :bathroom (ring.swagger.json-schema/field s/Int {:example 2})
   :parking (ring.swagger.json-schema/field s/Int {:example 1})
})
```